# Filter/Search Table on Two Columns and Hide Rows

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out the following; I have a simple JS script that filters/hides rows of the table based on a search value. How can I search two columns `td0` and `td1` at the same time?

```
function myFunction() {
      // Declare variables 
      var input, filter, table, tr, td0,td1, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

      
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td0 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        td1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

       // search first column
        if (td0) {
          txtValue = td0.textContent || td0.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        } 
       
       // search second column
       if (td1) {
              txtValue = td1.textContent || td1.innerText;
              if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
              } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
              }
            } 
      }
    }
```

I'm sure that this is not the right approach though. I am trying to search both `td0` and `td1` at the same time. Any help would be greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can only run single thread. If you really want to run these two codes together at the same time, you need to use `Web Workers` to use threading, but I think this will be overkill for this task.

You can somehow run it together by using `setTimeout`, but in reality this will not run in parallel because it is single threaded. Note: this is a hacky way of doing this.

Example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //search td1
},0);

setTimeout(function() {
    //search td2
},0);
```

I suggest you use `$.Deferred`, much better.

Web workers: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)
Deferred: [link](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/#:%7E:text=Categories%3A%20Deferred%20Object-,jQuery.,any%20synchronous%20or%20asynchronous%20function.)

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out. A super simple JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

I don't even know how I missed this. Thanks for help anyways!